# Crear nueva variable PHP o se puede usar la misma

Tags: php

Tengo una duda, actualmente estoy trabajando con single_html_dom.php para obtener datos de la web que yo seleccione. Pero me surgio un problema: Yo desde una misma página tengo que obtener varios `span`. Como hago en mi codigo para poder usar la misma variable e ir cambiando el identificador del `span`.

```php
$html =  file_get_html('https://www.futbol/inglaterra/premier-league/');

$img=$html->find("span.name ",0)->innertext;//el 0 el como un "id" según el orden de la pagina original

echo $img;
```

Como ven, si quiero sacar otro id con "span.name" tengo que crear otra variable idéntica, pero solo cambiar el número.

Comment: No hay problema en usar la misma variable para guardar otro span, pero si haces eso, obviamente se perderá la referencia al anterior cada vez que obtengas uno nuevo. De todas maneras, ¿qué te obliga a usar el mismo nombre de variable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tal y como te dice la documentación oficial de la librería, la mejor manera de usar lo que te devuelve `file_get_html()` es por medio de un bucle, más concretamente de un `foreach` dada su comodidad de uso.

```
// Create DOM from URL or file
$html = file_get_html('http://www.google.com/');

// Find all images 
foreach($html->find('img') as $element) 
       echo $element->src . '<br>';

// Find all links 
foreach($html->find('a') as $element) 
       echo $element->href . '<br>';
```

De esta manera el primer `foreach` lo que está haciendo es recorrer todas las `<img>` e imprimir por pantalla su atributo `src` y el segundo lo que hace es recorrer todos los `<a>` e imprimir por pantalla su atributo `href`.

En tu caso, si lo que quieres es almacenar todos los textos que existan dentro de `<span>` podrías almacenarlos dentro de un `array` para después usarlos cuando mejor te convega.

```
$mis_spans = array();

foreach($html->find('span') as $element) {
  array_push($mis_spans, $element->outertext);
}

var_dump($mis_spans);
```

**Referencia:** [simplehtmldom](https://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.io/manual.htm)

Comment: Pero si solo quiero usar 4 de los textos que estén en `span`

Comment: Pues accede a la posición de los que necesites con $mis_spans[0], $mis_spans[1], $mis_spans[2], $mis_spans[3]...

Comment: Tu dices asi: `$span=$html->find("span.name ")->innertext;` y para mostrar que span quiero mostrar `echo $span[0]`

Comment: Perdón. Me referia a ponerlo asi: `echo var_dump($mis_spans[0]);` pero esto imprime: `string(45) ""`